# Issue with PHP executing twice

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am displaying a list of filters using Isotope. The functionality works when the first part of the code works however, when the screen is resized the posts don't filter when it executes the last part... Any help is much appreciated!

```
<?php
    $filterLinks = array();
    $newarray = array();
    $starter = array('name'=>'View All','slug'=>'*');
    $filterLinks[] = $starter;
    $taxterms = get_terms( $customTax );
    if ( ! empty( $taxterms ) && ! is_wp_error( $taxterms ) ){
      foreach ( $taxterms as $taxterm ) {
        $datafilter = '.' . $taxterm->slug;
        $newarray = array(
          'name' => $taxterm->name,
          'slug' => $datafilter,
        );
        $filterLinks[] = $newarray;
      }
    }
    echo '<ul id="filters" class="desk-filters button-group">' ."\n";
    foreach ($filterLinks as $links) {
      echo '<li><button class="button" data-filter="' . $links['slug'] . '">' . $links['name'] . '</button></li>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    // Drop down menu on mobile
    echo '<div id="filters" class="resp-filters button-group">'."\n";
    echo '<div class="resp-filter-btn">Select Filter</div>'."\n";
    echo '<div class="resp-filter-content">'."\n";
    foreach ($filterLinks as $links) {
      echo '<a class="button" data-filter="' . $links['slug'] . '">' . $links['name'] . '</a>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</div>'."\n";
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

**Functionality Works:**

```
echo '<ul id="filters" class="desk-filters button-group">' ."\n";
  foreach ($filterLinks as $links) {
    echo '<li><button class="button" data-filter="' . $links['slug'] . '">' . $links['name'] . '</button></li>'."\n";
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

**Functionality Doesn't Work:**

```
// Drop down menu on mobile
echo '<div id="filters" class="resp-filters button-group">'."\n";
echo '<div class="resp-filter-btn">Select Filter</div>'."\n";
echo '<div class="resp-filter-content">'."\n";
foreach ($filterLinks as $links) {
  echo '<a class="button" data-filter="' . $links['slug'] . '">' . $links['name'] . '</a>'."\n";
}
echo '</div>'."\n";
echo '</div>';
```

Is this because i'm executing it twice, just hiding one on desktop and showing the other on mobile?

Looking for some direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So i've determined that when taking out the code that currently works, the code that didn't work while the other was there now works. So my question is, how do I basically run through the first. then run through the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `id="filters"` twice, which is improper use of the id attribute, since it should be unique. Not sure if that is of any concern?

Comment: It's to utilize this part of the JS.

  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

Comment: That code will bind the on click handler to only 1 of them. You should probably use classes instead.

Comment: So theoretically, will duplicating that code and instead of #filters - change to #filters-mobile work?

Comment: What is wrong with using a class? Instead of `id="filters"` add a class called `filters` and then change `$('#filters').` to `$('.filters').`. Or you could duplicate the code, but that is generally bad practice if they do the same thing.